# npx react-native run-android: Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run react-native-cli app on vs code.But packages are still waiting to be fetched remotely. Please help me. I get this output:
[image]

Things I've tried:

1. Android studio installation and create virtual device
2. install SDK commponents on android studio
3. install jdk 11.0.19
4. install node.js
5. Enviornment variables have also set correctly